# Hiding and showing listview without fading

Tags: android, listview

I am building an Android app.
I got an activity (ListActivity) where I have a editview and listview.
When I focus on the editview I am showing the Listview (which got it´s visibility set to GONE initially). This works but the problem is that the Listview is fading in very slow and the whole UI seems to be slowing down.

This is how I show the Listview:

```
mList = this.getListView();
mList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This is how I hide the Listview:

```
mList = this.getListView();
mList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I get this error message when showing the Listview:

```
04-02 20:45:42.260    9861-9948/com.fieldly.dev W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$SpellCheckerSessionListenerImpl.onServiceConnected(SpellCheckerSession.java:330)
            at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$InternalListener.onServiceConnected(SpellCheckerSession.java:469)
            at com.android.internal.textservice.ITextServicesSessionListener$Stub.onTransact(ITextServicesSessionListener.java:54)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Why is this happening? Can I remove the fade in effect?

**UPDATE**

The error is showing when starting to type in textfield. Not related to
showing and hiding the listview. I get no other errors. Just fading.
This is my complete code in the ListActivity:

```
http://pastie.org/private/oymgnc9y3njfwyxtjqzlgq
```

Thanks!

Comment: The stack trace you posted is something related to a `Service`, not a `ListView`. Can you please post the full code of your activity as well as the full stack trace?

Comment: @thomas-bouron I have updated my question with new information.

Comment: You have this issue with which EditText? Because you're using 3 from the activity you posted.

Comment: It doesn´t matter which one I use.